# SIP manual registration + Textview update

Tags: android, sip

I'm trying to write a simple SIP client running on android, I downloaded the SIPDemo project in order to get in touch with it, then I started to write my code and I'm encountering some problems.

Let's show you the code:

```
package com.example.gt_sipclient;

import java.text.ParseException;

import android.net.sip.SipAudioCall;
import android.net.sip.SipException;
import android.net.sip.SipManager;
import android.net.sip.SipProfile;
import android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

//Activity android simple pour effectuer quelques appels VoIP
//et réaliser des tests.
public class SIPCliMainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView numText, domText, usrText, pswText, callerIDText, sipText,
        statusText;
private EditText numInput, domInput, usrInput, pswInput, callerIDInput,
        sipInput;
private Button callBtn, registerBtn, unregisterBtn;
private String number, domain, username, password, callerID, sipPort;

public SipManager mySipManager = null;
public SipProfile mySipProfile = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sipcli_main);

    // TODO: virer les éléments qui ne seront pas utilisés au final
    // Get the layout elements
    // TextViews
    numText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_title);
    domText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.domain);
    usrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pswText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    callerIDText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callerid);
    sipText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipport);
    statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    // EditText views
    numInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_input);
    domInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.domain_input);
    usrInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_input);
    pswInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
    callerIDInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.callerid_input);
    sipInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sipport_input);

    // Button views
    callBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callbtn);
    registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
    unregisterBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unregisterbtn);

    // make sure that the screen will not turn off during the app lifecycle
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

}

// handle click events without implementing listeners (see layout file
// android:onclick)
// register handling
public void registerClick(View v) {

    // Get the SIP account parameters
    domain = domInput.getText().toString().trim();
    username = usrInput.getText().toString().trim();

    // TODO: penser à stocker le psw en MD5 et à le faire aussi dans le
    // sip.conf
    password = pswInput.getText().toString().trim();
    callerID = callerIDInput.getText().toString().trim();
    sipPort = sipInput.getText().toString().trim();

    sipManagerInit();

}

public void unregisterClick(View v) {

    myProfileClose();

}

// TODO: call handling
public void callClick(View v) {

}

public void sipManagerInit() {
    if (mySipManager == null)
        mySipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);

    myProfileInit();
}

public void myProfileInit() {
    if (mySipManager == null)
        return;

    // TODO: test si un profil est déjà présent

    // TODO: Load persistent data if they exist
    // SharedPreferences myPreferences =
    // PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    if (username == null || password == null || domain == null) {
        updateStatus("Please fill the form.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,
                domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        // important
        //builder.setAutoRegistration(false);
        mySipProfile = builder.build();

        // open myProfile for making and receiving calls

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.example.gt_sipclient.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,
                Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mySipManager.open(mySipProfile, pi, null);

        //manual register
        //mySipManager.register(mySipProfile, 60, null);

        // set SIP registration events

        mySipManager.setRegistrationListener(mySipProfile.getUriString(),
                new SipRegistrationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRegistrationFailed(String arg0, int arg1,
                            String arg2) {
                        updateStatus("Registration failed");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRegistrationDone(String arg0, long arg1) {
                        updateStatus("Registration OK");
                        registerBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRegistering(String arg0) {
                        updateStatus("Registering with SIP server...");

                    }
                });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO getMessage juste pour le debug
        updateStatus("Connection error." + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO getMessage juste pour le debug
        updateStatus("Connection error SIP." + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void myProfileClose() {
    if (mySipManager == null)
        return;

    try {
        if (mySipProfile != null) {
            mySipManager.close(mySipProfile.getUriString());
            unregisterBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy",
                "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

//TODO: completer cette methode pour se desinscrire du serveur manuellement
public void myProfileUnregister(){
    if(mySipManager == null)
        return;

    try {
        if(mySipProfile != null && mySipManager.isRegistered(mySipProfile.getUriString())){
            mySipManager.unregister(mySipProfile, new SipRegistrationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri,
                        long expiryTime) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri,
                        int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        }
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sipcli_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//Allez on va coder un thread propre pour la maj
public void updateStatus(final String status) {


    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusText.setText(status);

        }

    });

}

public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
    String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
    // TODO: watch it
    if (useName == null)
        useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();

    updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());

}

    }
```

Ok, now when I'm running the app, i have these errors:

```
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8581)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:6766)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:4617)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at com.example.gt_sipclient.SIPCliMainActivity$1.onRegistrationDone(SIPCliMainActivity.java:163)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.net.sip.SipManager$ListenerRelay.onRegistrationDone(SipManager.java:601)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.net.sip.ISipSessionListener$Stub.onTransact(ISipSessionListener.java:167)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
03-06 17:38:35.931: E/JavaBinder(3754):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The thing is that I'm trying to update a TextView for each registration step passed, I thought it would be ok using runOnUiThread but I'm obviously missing something. Don't worry for the registration, it worked well (it's a little slow but anyway...) and I could see the device on my SIP server.

My second question would be about avoiding the automatic registration: I would like the user to register/unregister himself to the SIP server by clicking a button (like in the zoiper client if you know it) I couldn't find any example about that, but if you have some I would be happy to read these.
If you need more info please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to move `registerBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` inside `runOnUiThread`. change `onRegistrationDone` code as :

```
 @Override
 public void onRegistrationDone(String arg0, long arg1) {
   updateStatus("Registration OK");  
  }
///..your code here....

public void updateStatus(final String status) {
    SIPCliMainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusText.setText(status);
            registerBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked, that was one huge mistake!
Anyway I decided not to set my registerbtn invisible for the moment because if I set it in this method, the button will be set everytime a registration step is done.
Any tips about my second question concerning the SipManager.register?